# Is it necessary to pay attention to npm vulnerabilities warning,?

Tags: npm

Most of the time wile installing new npm dependecies in a project, I get warnings and issues ( either low moderate or even crtitical).
And running npm audit fix, or fix by force doesn't resolve the issues.
Can I ignore them or should i fix myself ? Especially when it's about dependency tree

Answer (score 0):

Warnings are here to tell that a bug have been found and will be probably corrected in a future release. Nonetheless, to avoid breaking a package, an old dependency (which can also have issue) can still be used. So, those who maintain the package have either the choice to rebuild their package without the problematic dependencies. Or they wait that the dependencies (or work on it) get corrected.

if you want to fix yourself every problems of every dependencies of every packages you are using, you will certainly need to reincarnate thousand & thousands times on earth to clean that mess xD

the best is to have the less packages possibles. But here are 3 points i'm used to check before deciding to use a package or not:

- does it have a future ? (stars, download, last update)
- are there a lot of peoples working on it ? (forks, issues, pull)
- does it have too much dependencies ?

choose wisely can avoid you to fall into a devellopement nightmare.